# generate T4 classes from batch file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file, t4

I am working with T4 mapping to generate some c# classes for my MVC4 project. I generate the classes by right clicking on the T4 file within visual studio and select "Run Custom Tool". This generates the classes.

I would like to automate this so want to generate the classes using a batch file. Is it possible to do such and if so how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better served by integrating the transformation in your build as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx.

Comment: You need to install the Install Visualization and Modeling SDK for this, is there any other way?

Comment: You could try the TextTransform utility (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx) then.

Comment: No, I guess that comes with the modeling SDK as well. Why are you against installing the SDK?

Comment: For a team of developers, this means every member needs to install it on their machine which I am keen to avoid.